# How to get only integer values in array and how to add 100 for each integer values in array list

Tags: perl

I have an array that contains a list of values including strings and integers. Now I want to get only integer values and want to add 100 for each integer value. For example:

```
@array = ( "my", 214, 3871, "fg" );
```

Now I want to increase 100 for each integer value.

The final result should be this:

```
@array = ( "my", 314, 3971, "fg" );
```

Comment: This isn't supposed to be a "write my code for me" service. Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply iterate the array. Check if the current value is an integer and if yes, add 100.

The `foreach` works because it will alias elements in the array. It is not making copies. So you are editing the array elements one by one although you have assigned them to a named variable (thus making your code more readable).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Printer;

my @array=("my", 214,3871,"fg");

foreach my $element (@array) {
  $element += 100 unless $element =~ /[^0-9]/;
}

p @array;
```

**Output**:

```
[
    [0] "my",
    [1] 314,
    [2] 3971,
    [3] "fg"
]
```

---

Your question title says you only want the integer values.

```
my @only_ints_plus_hundred = map { $_ + 100 } grep { !/[^0-9]/ } @array;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the map function:

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Data::Dump qw(dump);

my @array = ("my", 214, 3871, "fg");
@array = map { /^\d+$/ ? $_+100 : $_ } @array;
dump@array;
```

**output:**

```
("my", 314, 3971, "fg")
```

Comment: The space bar is not your enemy.

Comment: I think the downvote we both got is for providing a code writing service.

Comment: @simbabque: You're certainly right! But, for me, it doesn't desrve a downvote.

Comment: I agree. Though I advocate for not providing the code-writing service myself, this one was simple enough not to not do it. Anyway, it's just one downvote. Let's move on, we can both take it without getting hurt. :)